# Need clarification for A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I think with A* algorithm it should be SAEFG, but the answer is SBEFG. Now my prof is a man of unavailability. Can someone explain why SBEFG?

Comment: Well, A* will indeed visit A before B. But when it reaches E, it will choose a path SBE, not SAE. The cost (black numbers) of SAE is greater than the cost of SBE. Red values are the estimated results.

Comment: A*: 1) A has est. cost 16, B has est. cost 18 (by est. cost I mean the real distance from start + heuristics). It chooses A. 2) B has est. cost 18, E has est. cost 16. It chooses E. 3) B has 18, F has 17, chooses F. 4) B has 18, G has 19. Chooses B. 4) Now the fun begins. It depends on the implementation, but if you want to always get the shortest path, you should in fact visit E the second time (since now E has real dist 11, it had 12). Then revisit F and go to G.

Comment: You can choose not to visit E twice and by doing that you will not get the shortest path, you will end up with SAEFG as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heuristic function used in the example is not consistent. For the heuristic to be consistent the following equality must be true:

For each nodes x, y: h(x) + w(x, y) >= h(y), where h(v) is the heuristic function's value for node v, w(x, y) is the real distance between nodes x and y.

In this example, h(B) = 13, h(E) = 4 and w(B, E) = 6. As you can see, h(E) + w(B, E) = 10 < h(B), so the heuristic is not consistent.

What does that mean? Well, the A* search with such a heuristic might not be optimal in graphs. It might not find the shortest path without revisiting some nodes.

In this example the author probably assumes revisiting the E node, so the A* will first go to C, then A, E, F, D, B and it should revisit E again from B, because SBE is shorter than SAE, then revisit F and go to G. The final path will be SBEFG.